# Parent and parents which one is appropriate in following context?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countable-nouns

> **A**: Sons of the same **parent** are called brothers.
>   **B**: Sons of the same **parents** are called brothers.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Why do you think that only one of them can be correct?

Answer (score 2):

Both of your alternatives are correct. Boys who share one or two parents are brothers. If they share the same parents (plural) they are often simply called 'brothers'. If they share one parent (singular) they are often called 'half brothers'.